# Blood hunter blood curses vs. remove curse/greater restoration

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, blood-hunter

Can a blood curse be removed by a use of remove curse or greater restoration? I've been looking everywhere, but I can't seem to find an answer. I assume it can be, since it is a curse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, probably

The term "curse" isn't really a defined condition in the rules, so we fall back to a basic English reading of the rules.

The Remove Curse and Greater Restoration spells both state they remove one curse affecting the target.

And the various [blood curses](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter#BloodCurses-1611383) of the Blood Hunter are, well, called blood *curses*, and the 'Amplify' parts of their descriptions tend to say things like "This *curse* lasts for 1 minute ....".

So although they are basically just magical effects you can impose on a target, they are "flavoured" as curses and as such I see no reason that any other rule specifically relating to curses shouldn't apply.

(I doubt it would have much affect on game balance to allow it either - its not that far away from one caster using Dispel Magic on some other caster's spell)